# Set an image inside CSS spinner and want it to resize it.image should be in static

Tags: css, angular

I am working on an angular application and implemented spinner using `CSS`.
Now the spinner working as expected.
I have added a background image inside the `CSS` using `background-image:url()`
Here, the problem is image also rotate with the spinner.

**Here is my `CSS`**

```
#spinner {
    -webkit-animation: frames 1s infinite linear;
    animation: frames 1s infinite linear;
    background: transparent;
    border: .3vw solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-top-color: #250463;
    background-image:url("../../../../assets/images/svg/img.svg") ;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
    opacity: .6;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
@keyframes frames {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
      transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
  }

  .spinner-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 998;
  }
```

**html code**

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" id="spinner">        
    </div>
</div>
```

**Experiment 1**
added another style **img**

```
img {
    max-width: 5vw;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 5vw;
    top: 0;
    height: 5vw;
    width: 5vw;
    clip-path: circle(45% at 50% 49%);
  }
```

i have updated my html code as well

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" id="spinner">
    </div>
    <img src="">
</div>
```

**Experiment 2**

added  `background-attachment: fixed;` inside spinner.Still the image is rotating

**Experiment 3 **
I made below changes.now its working

added new css

```
z-index: 8;
    justify-content: center;
    top:230px;
    left: 575px;

    .img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 42px;
        height: 48px;
      }
```

**html changes**

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" id="spinner">
       
    </div>
   <img src="../../../../assets/images/svg/img.svg">
</div>
```

One draw back is here.if i change the screen size,spinner and image appears different position

how can i solve this

Now the image showing some where else in the UI.
how can i include image inside the spinner.

How can i stop spinning my image?

Can we set image size

This is my first experience on CSS.If anything wrong please correct me.

Comment: Also edit the question with `html` code.

Comment: @SunderamDubey .Added the html code

Comment: Moving the background to `.spinner-wrapper` instead should fix it (I think).

Comment: @AlexanderNied .Required that image inside the spinner circle only.That is the reason i added background image inside the #spinner